# add member in Outlook using Java Microsoft graph SDK

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm trying to add user to a group in outlook using Microsoft Graph API in java. I've referred developer's guide : https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/group_post_members
for adding user.

However to achieve this I'm using *Microsoft graph java sdk* and I need to add the *json* object with member *Id* in the group in java, like

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{id}/members/$ref
Content-type: application/json
Content-length: 30
{
    "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}"
}
```

Please let me know how I can add the json object  in the body of the request in java.

My code looks as below:

public void addMemberToGroup(String groupId,String userId) 
            {

```
            Group group =  mGraphServiceClient
                                              .groups(groupId)
                                              .buildRequest()
                                              .get();

                JsonObject payload1 = new JsonObject();
                        IJsonBackedObject requestBody = new ReferenceRequestBody("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/78276c08-9802-4108-8b20-d70cff6666e5");

                        mGraphServiceClient
                        .groups(groupId)
                        .members(userId)
                        .buildRequest()
                        .post(user,requestBody);
```

}

With this I'm getting error as below :

SEVERE: Throwable detail: com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphServiceException: Error code: BadRequest
Error message: Write requests are only supported on contained entities

POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/5877490c-54fe-45fb-b288-b5d0f6902058/members/78276c08-9802-4108-8b20-d70cff6666e5
SdkVersion : graph-java-v0.2.0
Authorization : Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI[...]
{"@odata.id":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/use[...]

400 : Bad Request
[...]

Please let me know how I could resolve this.

Comment: This looks like it should work.  Have you tried making the request via [Graph Explorer](https://aka.ms/ge) to see if the service allows it?

Answer (score 0):

it should be like this:

```
User user = new User();
user.id=userId;

mGraphServiceClient.groups(groupId).members().references().buildRequest().post(user);
```

or

```
DirectoryObject directoryObject = new DirectoryObject();
directoryObject.id = userId;  

mGraphServiceClient.groups(groupId).members().references().buildRequest().post(directoryObject);
```