# How to update an Inbox message property

Tags: java, sdk, office365, microsoft-graph-api

Using Microsoft Graph Java SDK, I'd like to update an email property "isRead" to "True".

Using the API (not SDK) documentation as reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/mail-rest-operations#update-messages

I haven't been able to find the corresponding Classes and methods to do it.
I suspect the "singleValueExtendedProperties()" method to do the job, but I haven't been able to find any implementation or explanation on how to use it.

According to the API documentation the SDK request should look alike:
msGraphClient.me().messages(id).???

I am not even sure this operation is supported by the SDK; has anyone already done it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just use the isRead property:

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/{id}
Content-type: application/json
Content-length: 248

{
  "isRead": "false"
}
```

You can try it out in the Graph Explorer: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#

Comment: Thank you, but my question is not about the API endpoint. 
What I'd like to know is how to build the request to call it with the Graph JAVA SDK (if possible).

Comment: Ah, I see. Maybe these links will help: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java/wiki/Overview and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53140576/add-member-in-outlook-using-java-microsoft-graph-sdk

Comment: Its closer, but the Objects Groups and Messages have totally different methods, I am almost certain that the method I need to use is "singleValueExtendedProperties()" I just don't understand how.